# Compare argv[1] with first character of string

Tags: c, string, argv, strcmp

I have file with strings. Every string is on new line. Now i need to compare if argv[1] is same as first character of any of these strings. I am new in C and i am not sure that i'm using right functions

here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char character[100][100];
int i = 0;
int result;

while((fgets(character, 100, stdin) != NULL) && (i < 100)){ 
    fputs(character, stdout);   
    if(character[0] == argv[1]){
        printf("Yes");
    }

    result = strcmp(character[0], argv[1]);

    if(result == 0){
        printf("TRUE");

    }
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: `argv[1]` is not a `char`, it's a `char *`, so you need to compare `character[0]` to `argv[1][0]`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Well, `character`  would more aptly be named `lines`... does that clarify matters? [Hint to OP: Pay attention to names, they are important for understanding code.]

Comment: Oops, you're right, that's an array as well, so you can't pass `character` to `fgets`, you should `fgets(character[x],...)`, and then compare `character[x][0]` to `argv[1][0]`. Use `strcmp()` if you want to compare the whole string.

Comment: @Lee Re fgets: That, in turn, is true, too.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgets` expects an argument of the type `char *` while the argument `character` has type `char ( * )[100]`

You have to use `character[i]` as the argument.

Also this comparison

```
 if(character[0] == argv[1]){
```

is wrong because the both operands in the comparison are converted to pointers to their first characters and these pointers are compared instead of comparing the characters pointed to by the pointers.

At least you should write

```
 if( *character[0] == *argv[1]){
```

If you need to find the first record in the file the first character of which is equal to the first character of `argv[1]` then the while statement should look like (though in this case there is no need to declare a two-dimensional array)

```
char *p = NULL;
while( ( i < 100 ) && ( ( p = fgets(character[i], 100, stdin) ) != NULL) && ( *p != *argv[1] ) ) ++i; 

if ( i != 100 && p != NULL ) 
{
        printf("Yes");

        result = strcmp( p, argv[1]);

        if(result == 0) printf("TRUE");

}
```

Comment: You really should explain this. It's probably too subtle for the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure the `strcmp` is asked for at all. The OP's task seems to just compare the first letter.

Comment: I deleted my remark; it referred to the strcmp and was true until you corrected your code with `&& p != NULL` ;-).

Comment: Also, the 100 is probably an arbitrary limitation from when there was a fixed-sized array for the `fgets` and should for clearer code and better generality be dismissed.